# Firebase Function returns 400 from get request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

My local function works fine running on

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

but once it is deployed to the cloud, I cannot make the same get request to it, using postman. I get the following error on stackdriver:
   `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse`, and my request returns the following: `400. That’s an error.Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.`

The Data I send in both local and firebase is a `GET` request of type `application/json` with a body of:
`{
    "data": {
        "Celebrity_A": "Brad Pitt",
        "Celebrity_B": "Angelina Jolie"
    }
}`

What request is it the firebase function expecting remotely, compared to on local?

Below is the start of my function:

```
// Main index.ts
exports.funct = functions.https.onRequest(functexp)

// functexp file
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as _request from 'request';
const serviceAccount = require('./credentials.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
const db = admin.firestore();

export function functexp(request, response) {
    console.log(`request`);
    console.log(request);
    let celebName_A = null;
    let celebName_B = null;
    if(request !== undefined){
        celebName_A = request.body.data['Celebrity_A'];
        celebName_B = request.body.data['Celebrity_B'];
        console.log(`celebA is ${celebName_A}`)
    } etc...
}
```

Comment: Are you putting single quotes like that around your JSON?  That's not right.

Comment: Hey Doug, no that was just a formatting mistake on here, apologies

Comment: When you say "on hosting" are you implying that you are calling the function through Firebase Hosting [dynamic content](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)? If so, include your `rewrites` here. If not, I'd start with `credentials.json` which probably exists locally and not remotely. Note that you don't normally need that; you can just do `admin.initializeApp()` when running in Functions.

Comment: @Kato when I say hosting, I am referring to the fact it has been deployed to firebase cloud functions, as opposed to serving it from my local machine using the firebase cli. I can confirm that the config.json does exist remotely.

Comment: What if you send data as `POST` request? You don't see `GET` requests with body very often...

Comment: @KarloA.López Would you like to put that in as an answer, that has worked for me

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try to send your request as `POST` method, you don't see `GET` requests with the body very often, and that's why `POST` is more secure, it's never cached and most importantly there's no size limit, maybe that's the reason cause your `GET` request is not working.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That fixed it.  Is it common to use post to request data with parameters in the body?  My parameters contained private data so I thought it would be best to put them in the request body.

Answer (score 2):

If you land here like me because a 400 error when trying a GET call using POSTMAN a warning: be sure to not have anything in the body (I switch between POST and GET when testing and forget to se body to none)